# Marcar un boton y desmarcar el resto (Toolstrip)

Tags: c#, botón

Ya se que sera una tonteria, pero llevo bastante dando vueltas y me estoy desesperando.

Tengo un windows form con un toolstrip, que a su vez contiene una serie de botones.

Me gustaria saber como hacer para que al pulsar uno de los botones del toolstrip, se quede marcado este boton y el resto de botones se desmarque automaticamente.

Muchas gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien a que te refieres con desmarcar, voy a hacerte un ejemplo con lo que yo entiendo de tu pregunta. 
Al hacer click en un botón realiza una acción, en este caso ese botón cambia de color, además quiero que el resto de botones vuelvan a su color original, es decir, solo quiero tener un botón activo.
Para esto voy a crear un método genérico.

Este método recorrerá todo mi ToolStrip en busca de botones cuyo nombre sea igual al que yo he clickado, es decir el activo.

```
   private void Desmarca(string buttonName)
            {
//Recorremos el toolstrip en busca de botones
                foreach (ToolStripButton boton in this.toolStrip1.Items)
                {
// Si el boton no es el mismo que ha sido clickado
                    if (boton.Name != buttonName)
                    {
//Tu acción(desmarcar), en mi caso cambiar el color
                        boton.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Ahora lo que queda por hacer es añadir a cada botón el código para llamar a este fragmento.

```
        private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//Casteo del sender a objeto de botón
            ToolStripButton B = (ToolStripButton)sender;
//Tu acción, en mi caso cambiar el color
            B.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
//Llamada al fragmento que controla el resto de botones
            Desmarca(B.Name);
        }
```

Espero que pueda servirte de ayuda. No dudes en aclararme tu situación por si puedo ser más específico en tu problema.

Comment: Lo que queria era cambiar el valor del checked. Pero con tu ejemplo de cambio de color me ha quedado claro. Muchas gracias!